# How to truncate float values in XMM register

Tags: c++, c, assembly, sse

How to get only the integer part of float?  So, I have a float array: x[4] = {5.0, 13.0, 25.0, 41.0}; I'm putting it in xmm0 and then I'm making sqrt of it. I need one more command which will help to take only int part of this sqrt. For example sqrt of 5 will be 2.236068 and I need just 2.0 in an answer
Code:

```
__asm 
        {
            movups xmm0, x
            sqrtps xmm0, xmm0
            //here need some command
            movups x, xmm0
        }
```

Comment: If you did not have to use assembly, you could just typecast, using `(int)` before a float value.

Comment: @FlareCat no you can't, not in general at least, that will give bad results when the value is outside the range of an `int` or a special value.

Comment: @harold how about you floor it first, and then convert it to a pointer of type `unsigned long long`?

Comment: @FlareCat a pointer..?

Comment: @harold to allow for the use of `NULL`. Nevermind the pointer part, it wasn't that smart.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`roundps`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ROUNDPS.html) is the easiest. The rounding mode table is somewhere else but you need rounding mode 3 (towards zero).

Converting to an integer and back only works if the input is guaranteed to be in some range (about 0 to 4.6e18 because of the square root). You could do this with `cvttps2dq` and `cvtdq2ps`. That will only require SSE2, `roundps` requires SSE4.1. You can use `cvtps2dq` only if the rounding mode is set to truncate, which it usually isn't, so you'd have to change+restore it.

Answer (score 3):

There is an [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352303/avoiding-calls-to-floor) some of whose answers address the topic:

- [fmodf (fp modulo) function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2352736/588916);
- [float to int](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2352777/588916) (also mentions intrinsics, see below);

There also is a [paper](http://ldesoras.free.fr/doc/articles/rounding_en.pdf) discussing the float to int conversion issue, specifically mentioning the second answer ( no plagiarism implied ).

The major Windows compilers (at least) come with so-called intrinsics ( highly optimized inlined functions ) that might be of interest, eg. [MSVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xtcs5b25.aspx) and [Intel (float to int: p. 42; `float floor(float)` function and likes: p. 135)](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/a6/22/18072-347603.pdf).

**Caveat**

This is a researched answer. I have not personally used the referenced techniques.

Comment: OP asked for a truncating SSE solution in assembly/inline assembly, not FPU and/or intrinsics and/or rounding.

Comment: @rkhb Quote 'How to get only the integer part of float?' unquote - I did not read that to mean specifically a full-fledged sse solution. Neither does the Q headline suggest this. If the OP's code is in that domain, harold's answer seems better suited.

Comment: You're right that the OP should probably use intrinsic functions, rather than inline asm, because MSVC's inline-asm syntax forces you to use load/stores for inputs/outputs, rather than having data already in registers.  This adds another 5 cycles of latency, so it's pretty silly for a tiny non-looping function.  Most intrinsics are just wrappers for single vector instructions.